# Inno setup Arabic directories name error

Tags: c#, installation, inno-setup

I developed an application with C# in visual staudio 2012 , after completion , I want to make an Installer with .exe extension by InnoSetup and put every related file and folders, but the problem is , the directories and the files names are in Arabic alphabet( or Unicode in general), it gives me an error that the filename or the directory name is incorrect.
The number of the files are too many , I can not change them one by one , so I need a solution , how to make innoSetup accept any file name ,or any alternative software?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode), you have to use UNICODE version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adriano says in his comment, you have to use Unicode version of Inno Setup (the next screenshot is from [`download page`](http://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)):

[image]

That version, as [`this decription`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode) says, can work with Unicode file names (emphasized by me):

> Key features of Unicode Inno Setup are its ability to display any
>   language on any system regardless of the system code page, and its
>   **ability to work with Unicode filenames**.